# Current at specific moment in bridge circuit

Tags: current, voltage-divider, bridge

At the below circuit i need to calculate the current Iab at 300 μs,can i apply voltage division to get the voltage across the appropriate  resistors(30KΩ and 120KΩ)and by applying ohms law finding the currents and by using KCL at A find the Iab(t)?I am concerned as to if the use of voltage division is allowed across the 30KΩ and 120KΩ.

Capacitors initial voltage is 300V

[image]

Comment: Yes , these are linear nodes A,B

Comment: Does the time constant change after switch closure?  so consider this "non-linear response as piecewise linear in time. Req before vs after ?

Comment: Consider Thevenin Equiv. cct. How can it simplfy this?

Comment: Hi,thanks,it does not change this is from a linear circuit analysis course.

Comment: Good now Can U put your results in an answer in the form of an expression with time constants.

Comment: Node parallel Ra not = Ra//Rb thus Tau changes